# Can i set up Asset and Participiant ID automatically in the transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-composer, smartcontracts

I'm working with Hyperledger Composer and when i submit a transaction , i have to add  manually the ID of Asset and Participiant. Is there  a way to set up these ID automatically Without add it whenever i have to submit a transaction? Is there a javascript example code of smart contract ? Thanks.

CTO file

```js
 participant Patient identified by ID_P {
  o String ID_P
  o String name
  o String surname
  o String Birth regex=/[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]/
  o String CF regex=/[A-Z0-9]{11}/

}


asset Health_Provision identified by ID_CF {
  o String ID_CF 
  o Type type
  o String[] Date regex=/[0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]/
  o String NoteFromToDoctor
  o String NoteFromToCup
  o String Receipt
  o String SignNRE
  o String Priority
  o String Name
  o String Surname
  o String CF
  o String Birth
  o String Exemption
  o RequestSubstitution substate
  o Make_Health_Provision_Prescription[] requests optional
  o Make_Health_Provision_Reservation[] reqs optional
  --> Patient Applicant
  --> Doctor doctor
  --> CUP cup

}

 transaction SendPrescription {
  o String NoteFromToDoctor
  o RequestSubstitution substate
  --> Health_Provision IDCF
  --> Patient Applicant
  --> Doctor newDoctor
}
```

Logic.js

```js
function SendPrescription(tx) {

 var IDCF = tx.IDCF;
     
 tx.IDCF.doctor = tx.newDoctor;

 return getAssetRegistry('org.example.healthdata.Health_Provision')
    .then(function (assetRegistry) {

 return assetRegistry.update(tx.IDCF);
        });
```

I explain better : when i submit the send prescription transaction , i have to add  manually the ID Asset every time i want to submit a transaction. But i want to automate this transition and i  don't understand how i could do that.

In this image , when i have to submit the transaction , there are random  numbers associated to Asset ID , Patient ID and Doctor ID. I have to add  mandatorily the ID of my Asset ,Patient and Doctor manually  every time i submit the transaction? In your opinion can i automate that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZrgH.png)

Comment: Please provide your `logic.js` code.

Comment: When i submit a transaction with Hyperledger Composer i have to put the ID of the doctor and the ID of the asset. In this case the Patient choose manually the ID of the doctor because he has to send the prescription. But is there a way to make automated the insertion of Asset ID without writing it every time who submit the transaction?

Comment: Don't put your code in comments, edit your question and put your `logic.js` code and `.cto` file code there and talking about your last comment, you can retrieve all data of doctors and choose any random when submit transaction.